# In NotePad++ , how to filter lines with a style token applied to them?

Tags: notepad++

For example:

I have a notepad++ file with text in it as:

```
Line 1: Alpha
Line 2:Beta(applied Style Token 2)
Line 3:Delta
Line 4:Gamma(applied Style Token 2)
```

Now, what I want to do is, sort lines in a way that I get the lines with style token 2 applied to them on the top of the file, such as:

```
Line 2:Beta(applied Style Token 2)
Line 4:Gamma(applied Style Token 2)
Line 1: Alpha
Line 3:Delta
```

OR a way where I can see(filter) just the lines with Style Token 2 applied, such as:

```
Line 2:Beta(applied Style Token 2)
Line 4:Gamma(applied Style Token 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the style has been applied by some sort of seach, or that a search command can find the lines with that style, then: Use the "Mark" tab of the search panel (or menu => **Search** => **Mark**). Enter the search parameters, ensure "Bookmark lines" is selected, and click on **Mark All**. Expect to see blue blobs at the left of the marked lines. Now use menu => **Search** => **Bookmark** => **Cut bookmarked lines**, then paste those lines at the top of the file.